# Snap.js animate polygone points S.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, snap.js

Hello I'm struggling for more than an hour on this error, I want to animate my polygone morphing using Snap.js using the following code

```
    var endPoints = [137.3,270.3, 137.3,106.8, 125,106.8, 112.7,106.8, 112.7,270.3, 96.5,282.6, 112.7,293, 112.7,393.2, 125,393.2, 137.3,393.2, 137.3,293, 153.5,282.6]
    $('#c').hover(function() {
        console.log('test');
        $('.st0').animate({"points":endPoints},1000,mina.linear);

    });
```

But I keep getting a JS error saying S.easing[this.easing] is not a function, I looked it up online and the common answer I found was to use jQuery UI, I'm calling jQuery and jQuery UI in that order using their most recent CDN from jquery website.

I really don't get what's wrong and it's really frustrating